# Compiling app and library with standalone toolchain

Tags: android, c, compiler-construction, linker, android-ndk

I writing a application that is made with 2 steps.

First: Compile the libjson for android

My app will manipulate json in the native code. So, I write a make file to compile and generate a shared object ( .so ) of the libjson using a standalone toolchain.

Second: Compile the app native code with standalone

In the native code of my app I uses the libjson that I compiled before. And for compile and generate the .so of my native code I used standalone toolchain too.

In theses, all two .so are ok. Any problem is showed when I generate then. But... when I try load the following error is showed:

10-09 16:15:00.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2320): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "json_size" referenced by "libtestelib.so"...

1. "json_size" is a symbol from libjson
2. libtestelib.so is .so of my native code

What am I forgetting?

Thank you

Comment: Did you explicitly load libjson.so with System.loadLibrary("json"); before you loaded your library which uses it?  It's rumored that some devices will sort this out on their own, but more reliable to do so yourself.  Are you sure that json_size is an actual symbol instantiated in the library, and not merely a typedef or something you are supposed to instantiate?

Comment: @ChrisStratton it is a function:
json_index_t json_size(json_const JSONNODE * node);

Comment: @ChrisStratton, yes i load first the json lib

Comment: Verify in logcat that it was found and loaded.  Use the ndk objdump with the -T flag on the jsonlib to see if that function is really inside.  Also, is any of the code C++?